# Most performant way to check if elements are overlapping

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know you can calculate if an element is overlapping another by comparing the top|bottom|right|left properties within the `getBoundingClientRect` method. However, you need to loop through the elements to do so. I'm curious to know what is the performant way of checking to see if an element is overlapping any other element. For example, checking to see if label one is overlaying any other element. Then checking to see if label two is overlapping any other element including label one without using a loop each time, or is this the only way?

```js
const randomColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
// dismiss -- just creating less CSS
document.querySelectorAll('.label').forEach((x, i) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.label')[i].style.background = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
});

function overlayCheck() {
  let points = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
  let rightPos = (elem) => elem.getBoundingClientRect().right;
  let leftPos = (elem) => elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let topPos = (elem) => elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let btmPos = (elem) => elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

  for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    if (!(
        rightPos(points[i]) < leftPos(points[i - 1]) ||
        leftPos(points[i]) > rightPos(points[i - 1]) ||
        btmPos(points[i]) < topPos(points[i - 1]) ||
        topPos(points[i]) > btmPos(points[i - 1])
      )) {
      points[i].innerHTML = `${points[i].innerHTML} C`;
      console.log(i);
    }
    if (i === points.length - 1) {
      return
    }
  }
}

overlayCheck();
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.label {
  height: 75px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: orange
}

.cover {
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="label cover">Label 1</div>
  <div class="label">Label 2</div>
  <div class="label">Label 3</div>
  <div class="label">Label 4</div>
  <div class="label">Label 5</div>
  <div class="label">Label 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should ask this kind of question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com. It's not wrong tho, I just think you can find more helpful answers there

Comment: This may also be an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/). If you outline _why_ you want to check if elements are overlapping, there may actually be a better approach to reach your goal..

Comment: your code is not doing what you are saying. You are only comparing an element to its previous one. Not to any one. Do you confirm your code is not correct and what you want is for any (i,j) to be able to say if elem i and elem j overlap?

Comment: Agreed with @Dancrumb - this question could refer to anything from a CMS to 2d Game Collision detection, without having an idea of what you're trying to do and what would cause them to overlap trying to help you optimize is just best guess.

Comment: If an element is being overlapped by another I just need to add a class. There is other logic involved but I don't want to overcomplicate this example. @zfrisch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way thru trial and error. I'll post this here for anyone else who could use it.

```js
// dismiss -- just creating less CSS
const randomColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
document.querySelectorAll('.label').forEach((x, i) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.label')[i].style.background = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
});

//function to check for overlapping
function overlayCheck() {
  let points = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
  let rightPos = (elem) => elem.getBoundingClientRect().right;
  let leftPos = (elem) => elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let topPos = (elem) => elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let btmPos = (elem) => elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
      let isOverlapping = !(
        rightPos(points[i]) < leftPos(points[j]) ||
        leftPos(points[i]) > rightPos(points[j]) ||
        btmPos(points[i]) < topPos(points[j]) ||
        topPos(points[i]) > btmPos(points[j])
      );

      if (isOverlapping && j !== i) {
        points[i].innerHTML = `${points[i].innerHTML} C`;
      }
    }
  }
}
overlayCheck();
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.label {
  height: 75px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: orange
}

.cover {
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="label cover">Label 1</div>
  <div class="label">Label 2</div>
  <div class="label">Label 3</div>
  <div class="label">Label 4</div>
  <div class="label">Label 5</div>
  <div class="label">Label 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can improve this by making `j` start at `i+1`. That way, you avoid comparisons that you have already done.